# Zod: Create a primitive object from defaults

Tags: javascript, json, zod

I'm pretty sure this exists, but I haven't been able to find anything about it despite some digging. Say that I have a `zod` Schema like such:

```js
const Person = zod.object({
    name: z.string().default(''),
    age: z.number().nullable();
});
```

Is there a way to create something like this:

```js
const InstancePerson = {
    name: '',
    age: null
}
```

from the `zod` Schema?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know that I am a little late to the party but maybe it will help someone in the future.

You could extend your `zod` schema in the following way:

```js
const Person = zod.object({
    name: z.string().default(''),
    age: z.number().nullable().default(null)
}).default({}); // .default({}) could be omitted in this case but should be set in nested objects
```

Now, you can retrieve your desired output by calling:

```
const InstancePerson = Person.parse({});
```

Comment: This don't work with validation rules. How to do this while avoiding them?

Comment: Also this does throw errors when there is a non-default value, and Person.parse does not type the input.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be a direct way to do this sort of thing from the library, but you can dig into their `_` private fields and get the functionality you're looking for.

There are some risks associated with this approach because library maintainers typically don't guarantee stability in these private properties. If you're relying on this behavior you may need to be extra careful about version bumps.

Ok disclaimer out of the way, something like this is possible. Extending this to more types is left as an exercise for the reader:

```
import { z } from "zod";

const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number().nullable()
});

const schemaDefaults = <Schema extends z.ZodFirstPartySchemaTypes>(
  schema: Schema
): z.TypeOf<Schema> => {
  switch (schema._def.typeName) {
    case z.ZodFirstPartyTypeKind.ZodDefault:
      return schema._def.defaultValue();
    case z.ZodFirstPartyTypeKind.ZodObject: {
      // The switch wasn't able to infer this but the cast should
      // be safe.
      return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(
          (schema as z.SomeZodObject).shape
        ).map(([key, value]) => [key, schemaDefaults(value)])
      );
    }
    case z.ZodFirstPartyTypeKind.ZodString:
      return "";
    case z.ZodFirstPartyTypeKind.ZodNull:
      return null;
    case z.ZodFirstPartyTypeKind.ZodNullable:
      return null;
    // etc
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unsupported type ${schema._type}`);
  }
};

console.log(schemaDefaults(schema));
```

Here, I've specified no defaults but the code still outputs what you expected. If you specified "foo" as the default for `name` the code will output `{ name: "foo", age: null }`

A shorter approach would be to simply dig in one layer into the `_def` of your schema looking for `defaultValue` functions to call, but I think the given approach is more principled since it could be extended to support every core `zod` schema type.

One last word of warning, some of the `zod` types are not as straightforward to handle as others. Something like `z.number` could be reasonably given a default of `0`, but `z.union` or `z.intersection` would have interesting recursive cases.

It might be worth building out a library just for this handling or else opening an issue with the repo to make it part of the offered api.

Comment: Pretty impractical due to the limitations for unions & intersections, but still a solution. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I am really struggling here. Not only the unions, intersections, but also arrays and it especially does not work if you specify extra zod functions after an object like

z.object({name: z.string, age: z.number}).describe('user'), 

the 'describe' is last zod object referred to and not not the upper zod object, so the recursion of the zod object only works without extra piped  zod functions. Would it be a good idea to try to detect the actual top level ...def.innerType and then start testing what datatype actually needs to be generated?

Comment: Yeah that's what's rough about this approach. You'll essentially need to handle each type of zod object that can arise which means you'll need to be in lock step with the library and aware of the functions. I would say, unless you yourself are trying to make a library to handle this generically for anyone using zod, I would implement these features a la carte and throw in unimplemented cases to keep your sanity. What you're describing sounds like a viable option (but entails work)

Comment: Your solution is perfect for simple DTOs. I just added cases handlers for numbers, boolean, date and array. It helped me reducing code for creating default values for forms.

Answer (score 3):

So I have visited this thread a few times already and now I would like to give here my opinion,

because here is what my problem was/is:

#### I want to safely instantiate a new zod object by leveraging the defaults but also expecting me to input the required, none-defaults.

So the `.parse` functionality just accepts `unknown` and does not help me to understand *what* what I need to specify and what is a default.

Now if you have the same problem, where you want something like `MyZodObject.createInstance` then I might have a simple solution

The solution is `z.input<typeof MyShape>`

What this is doing is, it returns you the typescript type that is expected to have all necessary (required) keys and marks the rest, that will be filled in by the `.default` as optional.

So let's say you have

```js
const Model = z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    active: z.boolean().default(false)
})

type ModelOutput = z.infer<typeof Model>
// ^ type ModelOutput = {
//    title: string;
//    active: boolean;
//}

type ModelInput = z.input<typeof Model>
// ^ type ModelInput = {
//    title: string;
//    active?: boolean | undefined; // << DEFAULT
// }
```

### A generic Type-Safe method to instantiate a Zod Object with default values

```js
const makeInstantiator =
  <T extends z.ZodType<any>>(model: T) =>
  (input: z.input<T>): z.output<T> => {
    return model.parse(input);
  };

const instantiateModel = makeInstantiator(Model);
// const instantiateModel: (input: {
//   title: string;
//   active?: boolean | undefined;
// }) => {
//   title: string;
//   active: boolean;
// }
```